# Manually setting the namespace for a Service Reference

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, namespaces

When a Web Reference is added in Visual Studio the generated proxy class automatically uses a default namespace which consists of the application’s default namespace together with the web reference name. the problem is i have a profile web service which all my projects use that in order to authenticate. Because of the namespace i cant add a profile class as a link. Now I wonder if there is any way to manually set the Reference name? (or maybe there is a better way which could solve my problem.)
So far I've found this:

1- Go to the service `Reference.cs` and then rename the namespace.(the problem is every time i update the service the namespace goes back to the default)

2- I found this :[Manually setting the namespace for a web service proxy class in Visual Studio](http://tedgustaf.com/blog/2010/9/change-namespace-for-web-service-proxy-class-in-visual-studio/)(the problem is i have to change the build event which it could cause the unexpected errors.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Custom Tool" option with wsdl.exe and give the required parameters. Whenever you want to update the service reference run the custom tool by using below mentioned option.

```
/n[amespace]:namespace
```

For more information visit
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: thank you so much dear @Sathik Khan. but i really hoped there was a better solution.

Comment: You welcome... let me know if you find the one. Thanks.